# Toggle numlock without the key - without sudo permissions

Tags: keyboard, numlock

I have a keyboard without the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key. The keyboard is a Dell wireless one, similar to the MAC one. It has a clear key rather than <kbd>NumLock</kbd> like in older keyboards.
How can I toggle the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> on and off?

Comment: Maybe you can map a physical key you don't need on your keyboard to act as NumLock?

Comment: If the keyboard doesn't have a NumLock key, chances are the number pad doesn't support sending the alternate keystrokes, which means that even if you managed to map a NumLock key, it just wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have the On Screen Keyboard installed. In the dash, search for `Onboard`.

[image: Onboard on-screen keyboard]

The NumLock key is on the numerical page, under the "123" key on the lower right.

Comment: thanks, this solves the issue. I still wonder where the Numlock key is on my keyboard

Answer (score 6):

## Using super-user rights:

Install `numlockx`:

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Turn off <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> with `numlockx off`.

Turn it on with `numlockx on`.

## Without super-user access:

```
gedit ~/.xinitrc
```

Add the following line:

```
/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Unfortunately, you need the package `numlockx` for the above...

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately i do not have administrator rights. Is there a way to figure out where the numlock key is on a keyboard? or to toggle it with a click somewhere?

Comment: @dodohjk new edit